# How to fix "RPC pipe not configured" in Docker gradle attempting to clone gitlab repo

Tags: git, docker, gradle, rust, gitlab

I have a Docker container for a gitlab repo that needs another gitlab repo to build.  We are using Gradle scripts to do our CD/CI.  I am trying to write a step in the Gradle script to clone the dependency repo that is needed into the container where I build and test the dependent repo.  I have also tried to make the dependency a git submodule but that didn't work either.

Ok, we have an application we are writing in rust, call it `foo.rs` and it depends upon a fork of an Apache licensed open source project `bar.rs` (where we are adding features to `bar` and hopefully will upstream them back into the official bar repo), but we need to integrate the features and ensure they work with our application first.

So, we have two repos on gitlab: `//gitlab.com/ourcode/foo.git` and `//gitlab.com/ourcode/bar.git`.  I have docker container where I build and test `foo`.  In it we have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and a `build.gradle` used by it to do CD/CI.  Eventually, I need to get that working, but first I need to get using the Docker image for `foo` working on my machine.

The first step in the build pipeline is called `install_deps` (install the dependencies).  The code in the `build.gradle` of the `foo` repo that look like this:

```
tasks.register(`install_deps`) {
  doLast {
    exec {
      workingDir '.'
      commandLine '/bin/bash' '--login' '-c' 'git clone https:BAR_USER:BAR_PW@gitlab.com/ourcode/bar.git'
    }
  }
}
```

I created a DEPLOY_TOKEN on gitlab in the Bar repo with user BAR_USER and the BAR_PW is the magic string that gitlab handed back to me.

However, when I go to the `foo` docker container and type `gradle install_deps` I get back the error:

```
------ 0% Executing [2s]> :install_deps<-----
Remote-Containers CLI: RPC pipe not configured. Message ("command":"approve",
"stdin":protocol=https:\nhost=gitlab.com=nusername=BAR_USER\nPassword=BAR_PW\n"}
Remote-Containers CLI: RPC pipe not configured. Message ("command":"approve",
"stdin":protocol=https:\nhost=gitlab.com=nusername=BAR_USER\nPassword=BAR_PW\n"}
```

Where BAR_PW is, of course, the magic string.

While this is an improvement over my previous attempts.  The repo isn't getting cloned and if I try to do a `gradle build` it won't work at the repo isn't available for rust to use.

---

Other things I tried.  I tried making `bar` a submodule of `foo` by:

On the file system containing the `foo` repo (which is mounted by `docker -v /project/foo`)

```sh
cd /project/foo
git clone //gitlab.com/ourcode/bar.git
git submodule add //gitlab.com/ourcode/bar.git
```

And, the `bar` repo start out there but the `gradle build` appears to delete it and fails.

I also tried using the Cargo dependency to pick it up.

```
[dependencies]
bar = { git = "https://@gitlab.com/ourcode/bar.git", branch="integration" }
```

and also:

```
[dependencies]
bar = { git = "https://BAR_USER:BAR_PW@gitlab.com/ourcode/bar.git", branch="integration" }
```

But that fails because Docker doesn't know how to supply the credentials.

```
Caused by:
  Unable to update https://BAR_USER:BAR_PW@gitlab.com/ourcode/bar.git?branch=integration

Caused by:
  failed to authenticate when downloading repository
```